# How change css property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am simply showing triangle on top of a div as shown in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/wPWDm/19/.

I want a triangle for `MENU FOUR` to show on right side rather than left.

This is not working:

```
$(this).find(".dropdown ul li:first-child > a:after").css( "left", "300px" );
```

How can I fix this so that it detect this class and change the postion of `left`.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question.

Comment: If either of these answers solved your problem please mark the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Psuedo-elements such as `:after` do not exist in the DOM and therefore cannot be targeted by jQuery selector strings.

Usually you can accomplish the same thing by using CSS classes and the `addClass` and `removeClass` (or `toggleClass` if you plan on switching it back later in the code execution) jQuery methods - this will allow you to dynamically change the CSS that creates the psuedo-element.  So, instead of directly manipulating the CSS of the psuedo element through jQuery, instead write a CSS class for your `a` element that has the updated CSS for the `a:after` psuedo element and toggle that class when the triangle needs to be moved.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class of the parent element instead, and assign static CSS styles based on that new class. `:after` cannot be targeted by JavaScript directly.

```
$(this).find(".dropdown ul li:first-child > a").addClass('moved');
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown ul li a.moved:after {
    left: 300px;
}
```